DOS analysis from oxidation state
After aligning the bonds along Cartesian axis of octahedral for my system, I able to resolve $t_{2g}-e_{g}$ PDOS accurately (I have performed DFT+U calculation for my system in VASP). For $Ni^{2+}$ ($t_{2g}^6 e_{g}^2$) I am getting like this, Now I want to make understand my self why I am getting $e_g$ peak below of the $t_{2g}$ peak. Is this peak implying bonding $e_g$ states?

I'm sorry but this seems like the same question as you asked in April, except now you have eliminated the cell alignment as a possible reason for the behavior you observe. Could you say more about what if anything else has changed in your understanding since April? Otherwise, as far as I can tell, my answer given there still applies: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/12847/4515

I suppose that to verify whether an arbitrary state to which the metal orbitals are contributing is bonding or nonbonding or antibonding, one should at least also plot the ligand orbital pDOS. If the metal states do not overlap with ligand states, they are probably non-bonding. I suspect the filled $e_g$ states are non-bonding here.

@AndreyPoletayev I have uploaded pDOS with O(2p) projection, kindly have a look and do comment on that. The previous question which I posted on April that plot was with uncleared $d$ orbitals projection, but your explanation was to the point and cleared my doubts regarding that. This plot is with clear $d$ orbitals projection, but my question is what is the physical significance of getting $e_g$ states below $t_{2g}$ states.

@AndreyPoletayev do you have any explanation on this?
